# How to get notified about 3rd party library updates with Maven/Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

I would like to use the latest versions of 3rd party libraries I am using in my project without having to manually check for them or blindly downloading the latest version for the build. During some build phase I would like to receive a notification that a newer version of a dependency exist. Is there a way to do that with Maven/Gradle? Or may be there are better ways to get notified about newer dependency versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want this check to be made with each and every build, as I'd expect it will slow it down pretty much (and also add extra strain on repositories; imagine what would mean if each and every build, ever, would hit the mvn repository, every time).

The closest I came to solving this problem was with `versions` Maven plugin; it appears it has a feature which allows you to see the newest updates (check [this](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html) link).
This is how it looks like:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Build Helper Maven Plugin
[INFO]    task-segment: [versions:display-dependency-updates]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [versions:display-dependency-updates]
[INFO]
[INFO] The following dependency updates are available:
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact ........................ 2.0 -> 2.0.9
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api ...................... 2.0 -> 2.0.9
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-project ....................... 2.0.2 -> 2.0.9
[INFO]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils ....................... 1.1 -> 1.5.6
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 15 10:46:03 IST 2008
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

For maven, there's the [maven-versions-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

For gradle, there's the [gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin)